# Connect from one LAN to another LAN through SonicWALL

Tags: firewall, routing, sonicwall

I have a LAN (LAN 1) on the 192.168.1.1 subnet, and another LAN (LAN 2) on the 192.168.2.1 subnet.

LAN 1 is on the X0 interface, LAN 2 is on the X4 interface.

I want to be able to access a device that is on LAN 2 from a computer on LAN 1.

I am having trouble setting a route up for this.  I've tried creating a NAT Policy with a source of LAN 1 Subnet and destination of LAN 2 Interface IP but that did not work.

Comment: Of course didn't that work. The keyword you are looking for is "routing".

Comment: I've also tried setting up a route, that didn't work either.  I didn't mention that because it seems this isn't a trivial task on the SonicWALL and through my searching, NAT Policies came up as solutions for this more so than routing

Comment: You can use NAT, sure. You can also drill a hole in your knee and fill it with salt. Normally you do not need to set up routes between interfaces on the same router. Have you opened the firewall ports?

Comment: Yes the ports are open, and there are rules to allow traffic from LAN 1 to LAN 2.  It's puzzling to me because I don't have any issues connecting from a device on WLAN to LAN 1 for example

Comment: And from LAN2 back to LAN1? Last advice, because I hate SonicWall and never use it :)

Comment: Yep rules to allow that too

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create NAT rules, just firewall access rules. Make sure you define the subnet mask of both networks properly (255.255.255.0) and create a Zone for both LANs. Then create 2 access rules, [LAN 1 > LAN 2 Allow All] and [LAN 2 > LAN 1 Allow All], and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You just need Route policies in place, and they should have been created automatically for you when you set up X0 and X4. Make sure that the computers on both subnets have the firewall set as the default gateway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create LAN1 and LAN2 zones.
2. Create Firewall Rules opening LAN1 to LAN2 and vice versa.
3. (Create routes sending subnet1 to subnet2.)

Test without (3.) and do a traceroute. See where traffic goes and create routes only if needed.